# How can I change the module position from code in Prestashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I learn actually Module Programming in Prestashop 1.7.... hard work but really good.

So, when I install my first module,

```
public function install()
{
    if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) { 
        Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
    }

    if ( !parent::install() or
         !$this->registerHook('displayTop') or
         !$this->registerHook('header') or
         !$this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') )
         return false;
    return true;
}
```

the position will automatically set at the end of the hook displayTop.

Now, what must I do to set it on the first place ?

I have read it will works with the function "updatePosition", unfortunately I find only tips of 2012 and 2-3 years earlyier.

The developer docs have a hint here,

```
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/position-updater/
```

but I don't understand how to implant it into your module.

Does anyone have the time to explain me how the desired order is laid out by the code?
And does this happen in the install method or from where?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your admin panel, in "**Design**" then "**Position**".
Look for '**displayTop**' in the "**Search for hook**" search bar at your top-right.
Then drag and drop your module which is in the last row and place it in the first row.

Change module's position in the hook list

[image: 1]